# Move my chat app on regular url instead of localhost

Tags: node.js, socket.io, server, localhost, chat

I have made a chat server that listens on the port 80 for my website so everytime i want to access my website i have to open localhost:80 but i wanna access a regular page of my site and give it the same chat functionality that i just built. For example, i wanna show my functionality of chat when i open mysite.com/page.php. How do i do that? Because the people who intend to open my site will open my url and i am confused how to move that chat app from localhost to the real website of mine.

Comment: first host your chat application

Comment: Because this is PHP, its server side which means you have probably been using localhost to test your program. You should just move your application to a remote server that allows communication over port 80 as suggested by @uzaif.

Comment: Are you saying i wont be able to develop this site on client-side like using some localhost, xampp, etc. I will have to host my website and that chat functionality code too?

Answer (score 1):

- Find A Hosting Company (On Whose Servers Your Code will be hosted)
- Buy a Domain Name
- Set The Host IP as Your Target IP
- Upload Your Files To The Servers Of The Host
- Keep Developing On Your Local Machine
- Upload The Updates to The Servers.